# Error with install angular-cli with node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli, npm-install, node-sass

My system configuration:
debian 4.4 ,
nvm 0.33.8 ,
node v8.9.4 ,
npm 5.6.0 .

I want to install Angular-cli `npm install -g @angular/cli`.
But I get an error message:

```
root@contracts:/home/kalugin# npm install -g @angular/cli
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/ng -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
> node-sass@4.7.2 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
module.js:471
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
  at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
  at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
  at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js
module.js:471
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/lib/post_install.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
  at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
  at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
  at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-09T17_27_50_397Z-debug.log
```

I tried `npm cache clean`, doesn't help.
I tried change node version `nvm use v6.12.3`, doesn't help.

debug.log pointed to the problem with `node-sass` package. 
I tried install `node-sass` globally - but the same error. I cannot install node-sass...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Likely the problem is because you're running as root, and NPM disables scripts automatically when you do that. Try passing the `--unsafe-perm` to the NPM install command

Comment: Saved my 3 hours troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks man, i thought i was gonna commit a suicide: i stopped ng serve, rerunned it, and it crashed... A WTF moment!

Answer (score 4):

Try `npm rebuild node-sass` it can be a handy one

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19805375)

Comment: How is this not answer?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is due to use of sudo in command as it is disabling the scripts. Try npm install -g angular-cli without sudo it will work